# iOS - Multiple GMSMarker issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, annotations, gsm

I am trying to add  drag and drop functionality on Google map. Overall it is done but one thing has to fix. That is when I drag and drop GMSMarker on Google map pervious GMSMarker still exist and another (wherever I dropped it) GMSMarker created new. But I want only one GMSMarker. How to remove pervious/ old GMSMarker. Any suggestion will be Great. Thanks in advance.

Code :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

 // Mumbabi address

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:19.01761470
                                                        longitude:72.85616440
                                                             zoom:4];



// mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

mapViewGMS.camera=camera;

mapViewGMS.delegate = self;

CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([@"19.01761470" floatValue ], [@"72.85616440" floatValue]);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
marker.title = @"This is your current location";
[marker setDraggable: YES];
marker.appearAnimation=0.2f;
marker.map = mapViewGMS;

 }


- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
NSLog(@">>> mapView:didEndDraggingMarker: %@", [marker description]);


NSString *lati=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",marker.position.latitude];
NSString *longi=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",marker.position.longitude];


NSString * urpPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%@,%@&sensor=true",lati,longi];

[[ConnectionManager connectionManagerSharedInstance]sendPOSTRequestForPath:urpPath data:nil timeoutInterval:50 completion:^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error) {

if(!error){
    if(dictionary){
        if([dictionary valueForKey:@"results"] == nil || [[dictionary valueForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@"ZERO_RESULTS"]){

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self presentViewController:[ViewUtilities showAlert:@"Message!!" :@"Unable to fetch this location, May be this is an invalid loation. However Please Check your Internet Connection, and re- run this app."] animated:YES completion:nil];


            });

        }

   else
   {
    strUserCurrentAddressAuto=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[dictionary valueForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"formatted_address"]];
    NSLog(@"\n\n  *****  Great User address found,---> %@   *****\n\n",strUserCurrentAddressAuto);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //[self.automaticallySearchBtn setTitle:self.fullSourceAddress forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        UIAlertController *alert= [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:strUserCurrentAddressAuto message:@"Select this Loaction for ?"
           preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *pick = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Pick Up Location" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

               labelSourceLocation.text=strUserCurrentAddressAuto;

              // nil marker title (old title it is : This is your current location)

              marker.title = nil;


               locationSource = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:marker.position.latitude longitude:marker.position.longitude];

              if (locationSource !=nil && locationDest!=nil) {
                  CLLocationDistance dist = [locationSource distanceFromLocation:locationDest]/1000;

                  NSLog(@"\n\n **** Using Drag and drop Poin, Total distance in K.M. => %f",dist);
                  totalDistance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",dist];

              }

              [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


           }];
     UIAlertAction *drop = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Drop Location" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

        labelDropLocation.text=strUserCurrentAddressAuto;

        // nil marker title (old title it is : This is your current location)

        marker.title = nil;


       locationDest = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:marker.position.latitude longitude:marker.position.longitude];

            if (locationSource !=nil && locationDest!=nil) {
                CLLocationDistance dist = [locationSource distanceFromLocation:locationDest]/1000;

                NSLog(@"\n\n **** Using Drag and drop Poin, Total distance in K.M. => %f",dist);
                totalDistance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",dist];

            }


        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


                            }];
    [alert addAction:pick];
    [alert addAction:drop];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
               });

            }
        }
    }
}];


}
```

Comment: check my ans below, let me know the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the previous marker placed over `mapView`, it is the most preferable solution in this kind of situation or accordingly.

**To Clear `mapView`:**

```
[mapView clear];
```

**Use below code to drag and drop marker excluding previous one:**

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D pos;
    pos.latitude = marker.position.latitude;
    pos.longitude = marker.position.longitude;

    // this removes the previous markers
    [mapView clear];    

    // this method adds the marker where user dropped it
    [self placeMarker:pos.latitude withLong:pos.longitude]; 

}
```

---

```
// helping method 
-(void) placeMarker:(float)lat withLong:(float)lon{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D pinlocation;
    pinlocation.latitude = lat;
    pinlocation.longitude = lon;

    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    [marker setDraggable: YES];
    marker.position = pinlocation;
    marker.title = @"Hi";
    marker.snippet = @"New marker";
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    marker.map = self.mapView;

    // this always visible marker info window, comment if do not need
    [self.mapView setSelectedMarker:marker];
}
```

**Update:**

*To remove specific marker on map, just keep the reference of that marker object and later set it to nil see below code:*

```
// declare marker globally to declare its scope to entire class.
GMSMarker *markerToRemoveLater;    
// initialization and configuration 
markerToRemoveLater = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];   

// set nil where you want to remove specific marker
markerToRemoveLater.map  = nil;
```

Comment: @ Vaibhav, Working like a Charm. Thanks

Comment: welcome, you can accept the ans by hitting right button.

Comment: @vaibhav : But it also clears all markup, including markers, polylines and ground overlays. Is there anyway we can only delete only marker? In my map I have overlays but I don't wanna clear it. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it will clear all whatever on map, most preferable way is to put the polylines and other geo fences again instead of detecting and deleting specific marker this may leads the memory issue and unexpectedly app crash once you clear many markers aft alloc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was working on Gmaps. I wanted to clear the marker without using `[map clear]`. I came up with this solution.

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D pos;
    pos.latitude = marker.position.latitude;
    pos.longitude = marker.position.longitude;

    // this removes the previous marker from map
    marker.map = nil;  

    // ** Give your marker new position from  CLLocationCoordinate2D

    //Then 
    [self mapView:mapViewGoog didTapAtCoordinate:marker.position];
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {

    [self addMarkerInTheMapView:coordinate];
}

-(void)addMarkerInTheMapView:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{

     markerMYLocation.map = nil;
     markerMYLocation = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    //Your code here.

    markerMYLocation.map = mapView;

}
```

Comment: @ Vaibhav, your code clears all the things on Map, is there any way by which we can remove only marker please ?